# Is there a way to alter the request.path before matching the urls?

Tags: django, django-middleware

When I get a request for a path that includes the word 'self' I want to replace it with the user id before matching it to a URL. I tried using a middleware like this:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if '/self/' in request.path:
        request.path = request.path.replace('/self/','/' + str(request.user.id) + '/')
```

The replacement works but apparently is done after the URL matching. Is there any way to alter the path before this point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, the URL marching is not done using `request.path` but `request.path_info`. The same middleware altering this variable works.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to change the url, then match that new url? Why not have the url direct to the view and method you want, then work on the request.user.id like you would had you changed the url?

Perhaps another example would illustrate what you are trying to do.

(Making this an answer since I can't comment)

Comment: I don't want to modify the app and I would have to do it in every view. Something like this seemed to be a better option.

Comment: but you will have to edit the views anyway if you replace `self` with the id